# Issue with update timing for a state in React Component (2 clicks needed instead of 1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, setstate

I’m working on a solo project using React and I’ve been stuck on something for the past 2 days…I'm starting and I'm very beginner so it's maybe something very basic, but I'm struggling...

To try to be concise and clear:

I have a searchBar component, that searches through a local database, and returns objects associated with the search keyword. Nothing complicated so far.
Each rendered object has a button that triggers a function onClick. The said function is defined in my App component and is as follow:

```
changeState(term){
    let idToRender=[];
    this.state.dealersDb.map(dealer=>{
    if(term===dealer.id){
        idToRender=[dealer];
        }});
    let recoToFind=idToRender[0].reco;
    recoToFind.map(item=>{
        Discogs.search(item).then(response=>{idToRender[0].recoInfo.push(response)})
    })

    this.setState({
    objectToRender: idToRender
    });
```

to explain the above code, what it does is that first, it identifies which object’s button has been clicked on, and send said object to a variable called idToRender. Then, it takes the reco state of that object, and store it to another variable called recoToFind. Then it calls the map() method on recoToFind, make an API request (the discogs() method) for each element of the recoToFind array and push() the results into the recoInfo state of idToRender. So by the end of the function, idToRender is supposed to look like this:
[{
…
…
recoInfo: [{1stAPI call result},{2ndAPI call result}…]
}],

The array contains 1 object having all the states of the object that was originally clicked on, plus a state recoInfo equal to an array made of the results of the several API calls.
Finally, it updates the component’s state objectToRender to idToRender.

And here my problem is, onClick, I do get all the states values of the clicked on object that get rendered on screen (as expected with how I coded the nested components), BUT, the values of the recoInfo are not displayed as expected (The component who’s supposed to render those values is nested in the component rendering the clicked on object other states values). However, they get displayed properly after a SECOND click on the button. So it seems my problem boils down to an state update timing trouble, but I’m puzzled, because this function is calling setState once and I know for a fact that the state is updated because when I click on the button, the clicked on Object details get displayed, but somehow only the recoInfo state seems to not be available yet, but only becomes available on a second click…

Would anyone have a way to solve this issue? :(
It somehow feels like my salvation lies in async/await, but I’m not sure I understand them correctly…

thanks very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this someting you want to do?

```
changeState(term) {
let idToRender=[];
this.state.dealersDb.map(dealer=>{
if(term===dealer.id){
    idToRender=[dealer];
    }});
let recoToFind=idToRender[0].reco;
recoToFind.map(item=>{
    Discogs.search(item).then(response=>{
        idToRender[0].recoInfo.push(response)
        this.setState({
            objectToRender: idToRender
        });
    })
})
```

}

you can call setState once async call is done and result received.

Comment: yes!
It did work. Thanks very much!
I feel like I need to deepen my understanding of the promises and setState resolution timing, cause even though your solution work, I'm still not clear about why it worked in your solution but not in my original code, as it feels really similar :(

Last question: Would there be a way to achieve the same result but without having to call setState on each response?